# JavaScript - push results from for loop into array (with SoundCloud API)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, push, soundcloud

I have this function that iterates through a user's favourited track genres on SoundCloud, and then I want to push these results into an array however am having problems. Any suggestions?

```
SC.connect(function() {
  SC.get('/me/favorites', function(favorites) {

    console.log(favorites)

    for (i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
      console.log(favorites[i].genre);

      favorites[i].genre.push(meGenrePref);
    }

    var meGenrePref = [];

    console.log(meGenrePref);
  });
});
```

Comment: what is the problem with the code?

Comment: Try `meGenrePref.push(favorites[i].genre)`.

Comment: this is the error that I'm getting: Uncaught TypeError: favorites[i].genre.push is not a function

Comment: changed the code to: 'meGenrePref.push(favorites[i].genre)' and am now getting the error message:' Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert on SoundCloud APIs but watching your code I thought this solution:

```
var meGenrePref = [];
SC.connect(function(){
SC.get('/me/favorites',function(favorites) {

    console.log(favorites);

    for(var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(favorites[i].genre);

        meGenrePref.push(favorites[i].genre);

    }
    console.log(meGenrePref);
});
});
```

You were trying to push the contents to a wrong variable, which was the response from the API.
In this solution we are saving to meGenrePref all genres.